# GNU screen: how to automatically spawn a terminal after splitting?

Tags: gnu-screen

Here's the workflow:

1. Open GNU screen: `screen`
2. Create a vertical split: <kbd>C-a |</kbd>
3. Switch to the newly created split: <kbd>C-a TAB</kbd>
4. Create a new window / terminal in this split: <kbd>C-a c</kbd>

**How to do steps 3 and 4 at once**? Is there an option that could be added to `~/.screenrc` in order to achieve that?

(Note: I come from `tmux`, where splitting automatically spawns a terminal.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `screen`, so there may be better ways, but you can change the binding for `|` in your `~/.screenrc` with the line

```
bindkey | eval "split -v" "focus" "screen"
```

This make the key run the 3 commands equivalent to your key sequence.

Comment: That's straightforward indeed. I'll wait a little bit more to see if someone comes up with a more idiomatic way, otherwise I'll accept your answer. Thanks!